# Is there a way to populate C++ initializer_list with a for loop (or any other loop)?

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization

I need to create an interactive session in C++ where user can test a class I created. That includes creating objects of that class with its different constructors. One of them is a collection constructor using initializer_list.

In my code I can run:

```
MyClass example = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Now I need to find the method to use it during interactive session. Somehow I need to fill the {} with the input provided by the user. User can pass up to 100 argments in that list, so I probably need some kind of a loop solution to my problem. Something working like (Sorry for C++/Python pseudocode mixture):

```
MyClass example = {a for a in user_input};
```

Do you know anything I can use to solve this?

Comment: It's not possible. You're not supposed to do that.

Comment: A non-empty `std::initializer_list` is only created in contexts where the elements are listed all in one place.

Comment: It's usually solved with a constructor taking two iterators. Example: `MyClass example(user_input.begin(), user_input.end());`

Comment: I have seen some third party libraries that add Python style list comprehension to C++. It sounds like that is what is being asked about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::initializer_list` has a `constexpr` length.  This means its length is always known at compile time.  User input doesn't have this property.

So it isn't suitable to store user input.

A `std::vector` has a non-compile time length.  Consider using it.

Have `MyClass` accept a `std::span` or a `std::vector` instead of or in addition to an `initializer_list`.  (`std::span` is newer than [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)).

Then pass that in.  There are a number of ways you can populate a `std::vector` with user input.

Answer (score 2):

The source data for a `std::initializer_list` is *always* a braced-init-list: `{/*stuff*/}`. Only this grammatical construct can provide the backing array for this type.

`initializer_list`, as the name suggests, is for *initializing* something; it's just an intermediary. If you need to loop over some hand-generated list of items, this is what containers are for.